# Getting fopen/fwrite to write to different directory

Tags: php, file, directory, fopen

I need to write text files, i try with this code

```
public function ResultsTrackingLogs( $event, $message ) {
$logsDir = dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/logs/Results Tracking/$event/";
$fh = fopen( $logsDir . "$event.txt", 'x' ) or die( "can't open file" );
fwrite( $fh, $message );
fclose( $fh );
}
```

The `$logsDir` translates into `E:\Dropbox\htdocs\Scrapers\this`  beyond that the `\$event\` makes it so each event has its own subfolder.

Anyway I adjust..  I.E `/logs/Results Tracking/` ..  or `\logs\Results Tracking\..`

still gives me an error `fopen(E:\Dropbox\htdocs\Scrapers\this\logs/Results Tracking/event1/event1.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.`

the directory is there, I've created a .txt file there too, doesn't find it. the problem is obviously in how I describe my directory structure. how do i fix this? I don't want to create the directory structure before, I need it to create folders as it needs to.

Comment: What permissions did you give the file?  Your script will have to have write permissions to access it.

Comment: Does the error message actually say `$incomingvalue` in it? Because if so your variables are not being interpolated and you have the literal string `$incomingvalue` in the file name. In which case, you probably declared the file name in a single quoted string instead of a double quoted string.

Comment: i don't understand how to give a file permission in windows. When I use something like `$logDir = dirname( __FILE__ ) . "\\logs/";
        $fileName = $logDir . $event . " - " . date( "F j, Y - g_i_s A" ) . ".htm";         $fh = fopen( $fileName, 'x' ) or die( "can't open file" );
        fwrite( $fh, $message );
        fclose( $fh );
` it works, but that is not creating dynamic dir's.

Comment: @DaveRandom, no. it lists the values, I just changed them here. I will modify that to better reflect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the destination dir exists, create it if not.

```
   if(! is_dir($logsDir) ) { mkdir($logsDir, 0777, true); }
```

You could use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` if you want to describe a path.

Comment: There is no slash/backslash problem. Forward slashes work everywhere. Just about the only place they don't work is cmd.exe - they even work in the address bar of explorer.exe and the Run box.

Comment: @KiloJKilo The permissions argument is effectively ignored on Windows because it doesn't make any sense there, Windows permissions don't work in that manner. You could pass any value, the important thing is to pass true to the third argument.

Comment: @KiloJKilo: mode is ignored on Windows, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: @Fabio, Thank you this solution works. It creates the directory and writes the file. Thanks for you help. That is a big piece of my puzzle solved. Again, thanks.